# jQuery Content hover plugin in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

cSo I added this to my HTML:

```
                 <img id="d1" src="images/ann.jpg" class="img-circle center"/>
                    <h4 class="text-center orange"><strong>Ann </strong</h4>
                    <p class="text-center">partner</p>
                    <div class="contenthover">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat. </p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem</a></p>
                    </div>
```

And this to CSS:

```
             .contenthover{ 
             padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
             }
             .contenthover, .contenthover h3, contenthover a {
             color:#fff;
             }
             .contenthover h3, .contenthover p {
             margin:0 0 10px 0; 
             line-height:1.4em; 
             padding:0; 
             }
            .contenthover a.mybutton{ 
            display:block; 
            float:left; 
            padding:5px 10px; 
            background:#3c9632; 
            color:#fff; 
            -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
            }
           .contenthover a.mybutton:hover{ 
           background:#34742d;
           }
```

And then I added the JS file to my JS folder, ofcourse I also linked the script to the HTML code with:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $('#d1').contenthover({
    overlay_background:'#000',
    overlay_opacity:0.5});
    });</script>
```

.. am I missing something or doing something wrong? Watched a couple of videos and did it exactly the same, but still not working. - Very new to this

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: ReferenceError: mediaWiki is not defined, it says

Comment: And..SyntaxError: missing ; before statement contentHover.js:161